# Unity C# Action Delegates - How to Create List<Action> with different parameter types?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm hoping for some help here (I'm new to `C#` and `Unity`).

I want to create a `List` of `Action`s that I can eventually loop over and clear / nullify during the `OnDestroy` lifecycle method call.

Anyhoo, I'll mark below what I'm trying to achieve and what the errors are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Action delegate
    public static Action OnEvent1;
    public static Action<int> OnEvent2;
    public static Action<Vector2> OnEvent3;
    public static Action<Vector2> OnEvent4;
    public static Action OnEvent5;
    public static Action<bool> OnEvent6;

    private List<Action> ActionListToClear = new List<Action>() {
        OnEvent1, // all good
        OnEvent2, // Error as Action<int> is not Action
        OnEvent3, // Error as Action<Vector2> is not Action
        OnEvent4, // Error as Action<Vector2> is not Action
        OnEvent5, // all good
        OnEvent6  // Error as Action<bool> is not Action
    };

    ....

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        foreach (Action action in ActionListToClear )
        {
            action = null;
        }
    }
};
```

I've also tried implementing a generic type into the `List`:

```
private List<Action<T>> ActionList = new List<Action<T>() { OnEvent1, OnEvent2... etc. };
```

but that results in:

```
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone know the best way to create a `List<Action>` with different `Action` types? I.e. with and without parameters? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem useful.  How could anyone consume what's in the list given that they won't know what parameters to provide to any particular delegate?

Comment: @Servy I might be going about it the wrong way, but I want to make sure each action is cleared (has no subscribers) during Scene Load. I'd imagine there's a better way to achieve this? (I've updated my code to better explain my intention)

Comment: @thathurtabit Delegates are immutable.  If you have a delegate that represents the current value of an event, there's nothing you can do that delegate to clear the event.  You need to access the event itself, not a delegate that you got from it.  In the same way that if you have an integer field, and you get the value of it (let's say `3`) and put it in a list there's nothing you can do that value in the list to change the field to `0`.

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. Just set them all to `null` individually. Are you having trouble remembering to add a line to `OnDestroy` whenever you add another field? Comment it!

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks @Servy. Seems I'm aiming at the wrong thing. I may need something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.getinvocationlist?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @thathurtabit No, as mentioned before, sounds like you need to just set your events to null in your destroy method.  Trying to put the events into a list and use that simply isn't productive.  It takes no more work to assign the events to null in a method than to add them to a list.  `GetInvocationList` doesn't help you in mutating the event given the delegate out of it.  It helps you call individual methods of the combined delegate, but that doesn't do anything here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab at this. All the comments under your question are great. You have to think in a more object-oriented way. Here is an idea on how you could accomplish what you want and maybe get you thinking more outside the box. I'm not saying this is how you should do it, by any means. Just an idea of something you could work with.

So you define an interface, this is what all "Action" objects will have in common. You say in your question you just want a way to "Destroy" them, so we will force anything that implements it to also implement `Destory()`

```
public interface IAction
{
    void Destroy();
}
```

Now we create a "Base" action that can do 1 parameter that has a default implementation of what `Destroy` should do:

```
public abstract class BaseAction<T> : IAction
{
    public Action<T> Action { get; protected set; }
    public virtual void Destroy()
    {
        Action = null;
    }
}
```

Now we create another "Base" action that can do 0 parameters that has a default implementation of what `Destroy` should do:

```
public abstract class BaseAction : IAction
{
    public Action Action { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void Destroy()
    {
        Action = null;
    }
}
```

Then we create our actual events:

```
public class Event6 : BaseAction<bool>
{
    public Event6()
    {
        Action = new Action<bool>(x =>
            Console.WriteLine($"I just executed Event 6 with {x}"));
    }
}

public class Event7 : BaseAction
{
    public Event7()
    {
        Action = new Action(() =>
            Console.WriteLine("I just executed Event 7"));
    }

    public override void Destroy()
    {
        // do something special here
        base.Destroy();
    }
}

public class Event8 : BaseAction<int>
{
    public Event8()
    {
        Action = new Action<int>(x =>
            Console.WriteLine($"I just executed Event 8 with {x}"));
    }
}
```

Now we can create all the events we want

```
private Event6 _ev6 = new Event6();
private Event7 _ev7 = new Event7();
private Event8 _ev8 = new Event8();

public void Main(string[] args)
{
    // how you'd call the actions:
    _ev7.Action.Invoke();
    _ev6.Action.Invoke(true);

    // now remember, the `Action` member could be null if they were Destroyed... see below

    // you can then create an array of them because they all have "IAction" in common
    var lst = new List<IAction> { _ev6, _ev7, _ev8 };

    // you can also iterate over them and destroy them.
    lst.ForEach(x => x.Destroy());  
}
```

Comment: Hey @Andy, thanks so much for taking the time to hash this out!

Comment: @thathurtabit -- you bet. If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Now you've lost basically all of the functionality of the event though.  You can't subscribe with any handlers, you can't remove handlers, it can now be invoked externally, and cleared externally from the class.  This has solved one problem by creating 10 more.

Comment: @Servy -- He never said anything about events and subscriptions. His question literally is *How to Create List<Action> with different parameter types?* I was answering that question.

Comment: @Andy If you want to ignore the actual problem described and focus only on the title of the question and not the rest of its contents (which, for the record, you should not do) then you didn't create a list of actions, you created a list of a new type, so even by a literal interpretation of the question you didn't answer it.  But focusing only on the title of the question and not the actual problem isn't helpful anyway.

Comment: @Servy @Andy you're actually both correct, Andy is answering my question (my bad that it wasn't clear enough) but Servy is correct in that I do want to be able to have subscriptions to these actions. I.e. `Game.OnEvent1 += AnotherMethod`. Ultimately I'm running into the problem of my Unity scene clearing down objects but leaving the subscription attached (as I understand it).

Answer (score 0):

As a couple of kindly posters pointed out, the approach of adding all my `Actions` to a `List` to loop over during `OnDestroy` likely over-complicates the issue.

Instead the following does the trick:

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    OnEvent1 = null;
    OnEvent2 = null;
    OnEvent3 = null;
    ...etc.
}
```